# How can I export node data the same way you do webform data?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

We had previously used webform to collect data and our "power users" got used to being able to export the submissions to Excel easily. For various reasons, we've switched from webform to a custom content type. Is there a module out there (or maybe a module isn't even necessary) that would let these users (who do NOT have access to the admin functions of the site) to do the same kind of exporting of nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Views data export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module.

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft XLS (or really simple HTML understood by Excel)
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - XML